# Computational complexity of the FFT in n dimensions

Tags: math, complexity-theory, fft

What is the computational complexity of the n-dimensional FFT with m points along each dimension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computational complexity of an n-dimensional Fast Fourier Transform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249275/computational-complexity-of-an-n-dimensional-fast-fourier-transform)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a 1D FFT it's `O(m log m)`.

For a 2D FFT you have to do m x 1D FFTs in each axis so that's `O(2 m^2 log m)` = `O(m^2 log m)`.

It's too early in the morning here to get my head round `n >= 3` but I'm guessing it's probably:

```
O(m^n log m)
```

Comment: This is right, but it is really O(2^n m^n log m) - just pointing out that the coefficient grows exponentially with n as well.