# Minimizing distance to a weighted grid

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

Lets suppose you have a 1000x1000 grid of positive integer weights W.

We want to find the cell that minimizes the average weighted distance.to each cell.

The brute force way to do this would be to loop over each candidate cell and calculate the distance:

```
int best_x, best_y, best_dist;

for x0 = 1:1000,
    for y0 = 1:1000,

        int total_dist = 0;

        for x1 = 1:1000,
            for y1 = 1:1000,
                total_dist += W[x1,y1] * sqrt((x0-x1)^2 + (y0-y1)^2);

        if (total_dist < best_dist)
            best_x = x0;
            best_y = y0;
            best_dist = total_dist;
```

This takes ~10^12 operations, which is too long.

Is there a way to do this in or near ~10^8 or so operations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `distance` and `average weighted distance`? Your brute force seems to use the euclidean distance, but you're also multiplying it by `w[x1,y1]` for some reason. Also, you seem to be finding the shortest possible distance from one point to all the rest - is this what you mean?

Comment: ^ I meant **smallest possible sum of distances from one point to all the rest**, sorry. Simulated annealing might work for you, but I'm not clear on what exactly you want so I can't detail, at least yet.

Comment: A simple optimization is after each total_dist += ... check if it's larger than the best_dist, if yes do a break from the 2 fors

Comment: @IVlad: As the total of W remains constant (the denominator), minimizing the average weighted distance is the same as minimizing the total.of `W[i,j]*dist`.  I need an exact solution, sim annealing is approximate.

Comment: Please see if the implementation I posted below helps explain the image filtering method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Theory

This is possible using Filters in O(n m log nm  ) time where n, m are the grid dimensions.

You need to define a filter of size `2n + 1 x 2m + 1`, and you need to (centered) embed your original weight grid in a grid of zeros of size `3n x 3m`.  The filter needs to be the distance weighting from the origin at `(n,m)`:

```
 F(i,j) = sqrt((n-i)^2 + (m-j)^2)
```

Let `W` denote the original weight grid (centered) embedded in a grid of zeros of size `3n x 3m`.

Then the filtered ([cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)) result

```
 R = F o W
```

will give you `total_dist` grid, simply take the `min R` (ignoring the extra embedded zeros you put into W)  to find your best `x0, y0` positions.

Image (i.e. Grid) filtering is very standard, and can be done in all sorts of different existing software such as  matlab, with the [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfilter.html) command.

I should note, though I explicitly made use of cross-correlation above, you would get the same result with [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) only because your filter `F` is symmetric. In general, image filter is cross-correlation, not convolution, though the two operations are very analogous.

The reason for the O(nm log nm ) runtime is because image filtering can be done using 2D FFT's.

### Implemenation

Here are both implementations in Matlab, final result is the same for both methods and they are benchmarked in a very simple way:

```
m=100;
n=100;
W0=abs(randn(m,n))+.001;

tic;

%The following padding is not necessary in the matlab code because
%matlab implements it in the imfilter function, from the imfilter
%documentation:
%  - Boundary options
% 
%        X            Input array values outside the bounds of the array
%                     are implicitly assumed to have the value X.  When no
%                     boundary option is specified, imfilter uses X = 0.

%W=padarray(W0,[m n]);

W=W0;
F=zeros(2*m+1,2*n+1);

for i=1:size(F,1)
    for j=1:size(F,2)
        %This is matlab where indices start from 1, hence the need
        %for m-1 and n-1 in the equations
        F(i,j)=sqrt((i-m-1)^2 + (j-n-1)^2);
    end
end
R=imfilter(W,F);
[mr mc] = ind2sub(size(R),find(R == min(R(:))));
[mr, mc]
toc;

tic;
T=zeros([m n]);
best_x=-1;
best_y=-1;
best_val=inf;
for y0=1:m
    for x0=1:n

        total_dist = 0;

        for y1=1:m
            for x1=1:n
                total_dist = total_dist + W0(y1,x1) * sqrt((x0-x1)^2 + (y0-y1)^2);
            end
        end

        T(y0,x0) = total_dist;
        if ( total_dist < best_val ) 
            best_x = x0;
            best_y = y0;
            best_val = total_dist;
        end

    end
end
[best_y best_x]
toc;

diff=abs(T-R);
max_diff=max(diff(:));
fprintf('The max difference between the two computations: %g\n', max_diff);
```

### Performance

For an 800x800 grid, on my PC which is certainly not the fastest, the FFT method evaluates in just over 700 seconds. The brute force method doesn't complete after several hours and I have to kill it.

In terms of further performance gains, you can attain them by moving to a hardware platform like GPUs. For example, using [CUDA's FFT library](http://developer.nvidia.com/cufft) you can compute 2D FFT's in a fraction of the time it takes on a CPU. The key point is, that the FFT method will scale as you throw more hardware to do the computation, while the brute force method will scale much worse.

### Observations

While implementing this, I have observed that almost every time, the `best_x,bext_y` values are one of `floor(n/2)+-1`. This means that most likely the distance term dominates the entire computation, therefore, you could get away with computing the value of `total_dist` for only 4 values, making this algorithm trivial!

Comment: Nice!  Although, wouldn't it be O(n m log(n m)) instead, from the 2D FFT used to do the convolutions?

Comment: In 2D, you need to compute an FFT along each dimension hence the `n log(n)` and `m log(m)` terms multiplied together (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514861/computational-complexity-of-the-fft-in-n-dimensions). If m = n then it becomes O( n^2 log(n)^2) = O ( 2 n^2 log(n) ) = O ( n^2 log(n) )

Comment: What is the operator here: `R = F o W` ?  Is this matrix multiplication?  I have not heard of filtering in this context.  Can you provide a wikipedia reference to the technique?

Comment: @ldog:  The FFT's along each dimension can be performed independently along each row and column.  So, one set will take `O(n m log m)`, and the other set will take `O(m n log n)`, for a total of `O(n m (log n + log m)) = O(n m log(n m))`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling -- it is [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), and it is more commonly written with an asterisk:  `[F * W](x) = integral[y](F(x-y) W(y))`

Comment: @comingstorm: Ahh thanks, yea I wasn't entirely sure on the complexity.  It isn't exactly convolution, rather cross-correlation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation