# Computational complexity of an n-dimensional Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: math, fft, big-o

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will predict the time taken to perform a discrete Fourier transform on a given n-dimensional array, but I'm struggling to get my head around the computational complexity of n-dimensional FFTs.

As I understand it:

- The 1D FFT of a vector of length `N` should take `k*(N*log(N))` where `k` is some timing constant
- For an `M*N` matrix, the 2D FFT should take:

  `N*(k*M*log(M)) + M*(k*N*log(N)) = k*M*N*(log(M)+log(N))`

  since it requires taking 1D FFTs in each row and column

How does this generalize to the ND case? Does it follow that it should be `k*prod(dimensions)*sum(log(dimensions))`?

Comment: @vaxquis true, but Mystical's answer is much better :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we take your derivation of 2D a bit further, it becomes clear:

```
N*(k*M*log(M)) + M*(k*N*log(N)) = k*M*N*(log(M)+log(N))
```

becomes:

```
                                = k*M*N*(log(M*N))
```

For N dimensions (A,B,C, etc...), the complexity is:

```
O( A*B*C*... * log(A*B*C*...) )
```

Mathematically speaking, an N-Dimensional FFT is the same as a 1-D FFT with the size of the product of the dimensions, except that the [twiddle factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twiddle_factor) are different. So it naturally follows that the computational complexity is the same.

Comment: Ah, of course - how silly of me! Thanks for clearing that up...