# Computational complexity of n-dimensional Discrete Fourier Transform?

Tags: math, fft, complexity-theory, dft

The [computational complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) of n-dimensional Fast Fourier Transform was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514861/computational-complexity-of-the-fft-in-n-dimensions) and (as the former's duplicate) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249275/computational-complexity-of-an-n-dimensional-fast-fourier-transform).

The computational complexity of a 1-dimensional [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) is [`O(N^2)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), `N` is the data set size.

Could you please tell us what is the computational complexity of the n-dimensional Discrete Fourier Transform consisting {N1, N2 ... Nn} points along each dimension?

Comment: cs.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place to ask this Q

Comment: @Curcuma_ I kindly disagree. The linked (similar) questions were asked within this stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT itself is also a DFT (with some constraints). Will assume that you mean the naive summation method.

Re-writing the 1D DFT in integral form (the continuous version):

[image]

A particular value of `f`-tilde is equivalent to a single element in your DFT array. When the integral is *discretized* (i.e. converted a finite sum), there are `N` terms in the sum. This gives `O(N)` for each element and hence `O(N^2)` overall.

In case you were wondering, writing in this form allows for more compact notation for a general `n`-D DFT:

[image]

When this is discretized, we can see that for each element there are `n` sums, each over one of the dimensions and of length `N`. There are `N ^ n` values in the input "array", so the complexity is:

[image]